# How to install a particular version of helm?

Tags: shell, kubernetes, command, version, kubernetes-helm

I am installing helm through a script which uses these commands to install the latest version -

```
curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3.2.0
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
```

however , i don't want it to install the latest versions always. how can i install the version v3.2.4 always?

Comment: you can download and install any version from helm releases in github
https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.2.4

Comment: @edbighead please elaborate more and post is as an answer. You have my upvote.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find all the versions of helm binaries on [Helm Releases page](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases)

If you want to install [v3.2.4](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.2.4)

```
$ wget https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.2.4-linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf helm-v3.2.4-linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ sudo mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.4", GitCommit:"0ad800ef43d3b826f31a5ad8dfbb4fe05d143688", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.12"}
```

[Documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/#from-the-binary-releases)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to use the `DESIRED_VERSION` environment variable to specify the version ([by github tag](https://github.com/helm/helm/tags)) that should be installed by the `get_helm.sh` script.

```
curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
DESIRED_VERSION=v3.2.4 ./get_helm.sh
helm version
```

console output:

```
Helm v3.2.4 is available. Changing from version v3.5.0.
Downloading https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.2.4-linux-amd64.tar.gz
Verifying checksum... Done.
Preparing to install helm into /usr/local/bin
helm installed into /usr/local/bin/helm
...
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.4", 
GitCommit:"0ad800ef43d3b826f31a5ad8dfbb4fe05d143688",
GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.12"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `--version` option to specify desired version

```
$ ./get_helm.sh -h
Accepted cli arguments are:
[--help|-h ] ->> prints this help
[--version|-v <desired_version>] . When not defined it fetches the latest release from GitHub e.g. --version v3.0.0 or -v canary
[--no-sudo]  ->> install without sudo
```